# After a user login all campaign data in ga4 is 0

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

I've implemented custom event tracking in my Flutter app to monitor user behavior, including data associated with Google Ads campaigns.

Users access my app through Google Ads campaigns, and I'm successfully capturing campaign-specific data.

The Issue:

The problem arises when a user signs in using Firebase Authentication. Prior to sign-in, I can view and access campaign data without any issues. However, after a user signs in, it seems that the campaign data gets to zero.

like in the image the user can go upto FA3 with out logging in but FA4 is with the user logs in (pracharify is my campaign name)
[image: here is an the data from ga4]

Specifically:

Data associated with the campaign is visible when the user is not signed in. However, after the user signs in using Firebase Authentication, the campaign data is no longer accessible. Questions:

Why is this happening?: I'm curious about the underlying cause of this issue. Why would Firebase Authentication impact the retention of campaign data?

How can I prevent this from happening?: What steps can I take to ensure that the campaign data remains intact even after a user signs in via Firebase Authentication?